# Why do Chromium and Chrome delete sign-in cookies after closing the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, cookies

I am unable to stay signed in on Chromium and Google Chrome. I sign in to website A, close all tabs, open website A again, and am still signed in. I quit Chromium or Google Chrome, open website A, and have to sign in again.

Curiously, the website has cookies stored. Here is an example of cookies from StackOverflow saved on the browser, which looks the same for Chromium and Chrome:

[image: saved cookies]

I believe the problem is from Chromium because I can stay signed in on website A on other browsers. I checked [this thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2211795?hl=en) and confirm that at `chrome://settings/content/cookies`, I have disabled `Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome`. That issue seems to continue unsolved.

Another problem that could be related is that each time I launch Chromium or Chrome, I get these two alerts, as if I were launching it for the first time:

[image: alert about incoming network connections]

[image: alert about keychain access]

Brave, which is also based on Chromium, does not give these problems.

For reference, my settings do not ask to clear cookies after restarting:

[image: cookie settings]

I updated Chromium (Version 86.0.4207.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit), 18 July 2020) and Google Chrome (Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit), 18 July 2020). I am using macOS 10.14.6.

How can I stay signed in on a website with Chromium or Chrome?

Note: originally posted on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390792/why-do-chromium-and-chrome-delete-all-cookies-after-closing-the-browser).